# aiohttp download large list of pdf files

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

i am trying to download large number of pdf files asynchronously, python requests does not work well with `async` functionalities

but i am finding `aiohttp` hard to implement with pdf downloads, and can't find a thread for this specific task, for someone new into python `async` world to understand easily.

yeah it can be done with `threadpoolexecutor` but in this case better to keep in one thread.

this code works but need to do with 100 or so urls
asynchronously

```
import aiohttp        
import aiofiles

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    url = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            f = await aiofiles.open('download_pdf.pdf', mode='wb')
            await f.write(await resp.read())
            await f.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do try something like this. For the sake of simplicity the same dummy pdf will be downloaded multiple times to disk with different file names:

```py
from asyncio import Semaphore, gather, run, wait_for
from random import randint

import aiofiles
from aiohttp.client import ClientSession

# Mock a list of different pdfs to download
pdf_list = [
    "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
    "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
    "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
]

MAX_TASKS = 5
MAX_TIME = 5


async def download(pdf_list):
    tasks = []
    sem = Semaphore(MAX_TASKS)

    async with ClientSession() as sess:
        for pdf_url in pdf_list:
            # Mock a different file name each iteration
            dest_file = str(randint(1, 100000)) + ".pdf"
            tasks.append(
                # Wait max 5 seconds for each download
                wait_for(
                    download_one(pdf_url, sess, sem, dest_file),
                    timeout=MAX_TIME,
                )
            )

        return await gather(*tasks)


async def download_one(url, sess, sem, dest_file):
    async with sem:
        print(f"Downloading {url}")
        async with sess.get(url) as res:
            content = await res.read()

        # Check everything went well
        if res.status != 200:
            print(f"Download failed: {res.status}")
            return

        async with aiofiles.open(dest_file, "+wb") as f:
            await f.write(content)
            # No need to use close(f) when using with statement


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(download(pdf_list))
```

Keep in mind that firing multiple concurrent request to a server might get your IP banned for a period of time. In that case, consider adding a sleep call (which kind of defeats the purpose of using `aiohttp`) or switching to a classic sequential script. In order to keep things concurrent but kinder to the server, the script will fire max **5** requests at any given time (`MAX_TASKS`).

Comment: this works perfectly for what i wanted to achieve, sorry i forgot to choose your answer as chosen answer, i just noticed that i didn't do it initially.